# Using <xsl:choose> to format an element depending on its ancestor element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to use test in an <xsl:when> element to see if the current node is a descendant of an earlier node. I then want to apply the appropriate html tag to the content. I am a novice with xpath expressions.

Specifically, I would like to apply <th> tags to the <tcell> elements that are descendants of the <thead> element. I would like to apply <td> tags to the <tcell> elements that are descendants of the <tbody> elements. My best guess is that I have to use an <xsl:choose> element in my <xsl:template match="tcell"> element. I have tried a few different xpath expressions in the test, but none of them have worked.

**Question:** Is <xsl:choose> the best option for this?

Here is my xml document, the applicable part. The document structure cannot be changed.

```
<table>
  <tgroup>
    <thead>
      <trow>
        <tcell>Column Head Text</tcell>
        <tcell>Column Head Text</tcell>
      </trow>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <trow>
        <tcell>Cell Text</tcell>
        <tcell>Cell Text</tcell>
      </trow>        
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
 </table>
```

I want to use XSL/XPath to generate a table with a header row and body rows. My XSL stylesheet looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply templates />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tgroup">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead">
    <thead>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </thead>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>       

<xsl:template match="trow">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<!-- MY TROUBLE STARTS HERE -->
<xsl:template match="tcell">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current()!=descendant::tbody">
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </th>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Sample html output**

```
<table>
  <tgroup>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Column Head Text</th>
      <th>Column Head Text</th>
     <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Cell Text</td>
       <td>Cell Text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
 </table>
```

Thanks,
M_66

Comment: Show the desired output xml please

Comment: The desired xml output would be:<br /><pre><code><table><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="thead//tcell">
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody//tcell">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

or if you still want to use `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:template match="tcell">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::thead">
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </th>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but I was given an xsl stylesheet template with all the elements specifically matched. Is there a way to do it without adding another <xsl:template match="">? Basically I have to work with what was given me. That is why I was hoping to be able to specify conditions within the <xsl:template match="tcell"> element. Thanks for the quick response. Also, is what I'm attempting possible?

Comment: @M_66: Remember this *rule*: In XSLT *always* prefer using template matching rather than using explicit conditionals. Let the XSLT processor do the work for you and thus have shorter and simpler code that is easy to understand, more flexible and not so error-prone.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I have limited experience with XSLT, but your recommendation does make sense. I would have preferred that method if it was an option, but it wasn't so I had to go with the explicit conditionals. It did seem like it would have been easier.